# Python Selenium select Bootstrap drop down menu

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I select an element from a Bootstrap dropdown using Python Selenium? My HTML for the drop down looks something like:

```
  <select type="select" class="selectpicker form-control" id="selFoo" >
        <option data-hidden="true">Make a selection</option>

        <option>Foo</option>
        <option>Bar</option>
        <option>Baz</option>

  </select>
```

I have tried using the selenium Select module but get an error like:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted
```

Comment: Give WebDriver wait.

Comment: Are you using javascript to update the dropdown?

Comment: @patricmj no as I said I am using the Select module, which doesn't work as Bootstrap hides the select element and replaces it with its own stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to select "Bar" from the example drop-down, do something like this:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
browser.get(hostname)
sleep(1) # wait for page to render    

dropdown = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[data-id=selFoo]")
dropdown.click()
sleep(1) # probably not necessary
option   = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("ul[role=menu] a[data-normalized-text='<span class=\"text\">Bar</span>']")
option.click()
```

Tested in Firefox only.

Comment: Did you post this question to answer your own question? This is correct. How do you un-hide 'data-hidden = True'? Click it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Select` module of `Selenium`. Try the below code piece :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import selenium.webdriver.support.select

dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(#selFoo))
dropdown.select_by_value('Foo')   # will select Foo option
```

For more detail refer [Select](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html)... Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't work with Bootstrap as the select element is invisible.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

dropdown = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id("selFoo")))
dropdown.select_by_visible_text("Baz")
```

This should work. If it doesn`t you can try add this before these two lines.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active === 0"))
```

That will make sure nothing is happening before jQuery is done.

Comment: This does not work as it has nothing to do with waiting, Bootstrap HIDES your select element so it NEVER becomes visible no longer how long you wait.